# Customizing the Error Message Format for an Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale

Whenever I submit a form with an email already taken I receive the following error:

```
Avatar email email Email has already been taken.
```

In my locale I have

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        avatar_email:
          attributes:
            email:
              format: '%{message}'
              taken: 'Email has already been taken'
```

I thought the format attribute would fix it but it's still rendering the attribute and the message. How do I fix the locale file to set so the message returned is `Email has already been taken`?